# LinkedIn API "Client Secret missing" - Streamlit

Tags: python, oauth, linkedin-api, streamlit

[image: Error Message]

Purpose of this application: Retrieve basic profile information from LinkedIn.
I always receive the error message even though the client_id and the client_secret are definitely correct. Appreciate your help folks!

Code:

```py
import streamlit as st
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError

# Constants
CLIENT_ID = 'Key_01'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'Key_02'
REDIRECT_URI = 'https://kup7u2ixdrj2gdn6wmq3er.streamlit.app/'
AUTHORIZATION_BASE_URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization'
TOKEN_URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken'
SCOPE = 'openid profile email'

# Function to parse query string
def get_query_params():
    params = st.experimental_get_query_params()
    return {k: v[0] for k, v in params.items() if v}

# Start the OAuth process
def start_oauth():
    linkedin = OAuth2Session(CLIENT_ID, redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI, scope=SCOPE)
    authorization_url, state = linkedin.authorization_url(AUTHORIZATION_BASE_URL)
    st.session_state['oauth_state'] = state
    st.markdown(f"[Log in with LinkedIn]({authorization_url})", unsafe_allow_html=True)

# Fetch token and user info
def fetch_token_and_user_info(code):
    try:
        linkedin = OAuth2Session(CLIENT_ID, redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI)
        token = linkedin.fetch_token(
            TOKEN_URL,
            client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
            code=code
        )
        st.session_state['oauth_token'] = token
        st.write("Received token:", token)

        user_info = linkedin.get('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me', headers={
            'Authorization': f'Bearer {token["access_token"]}'
        }).json()
        st.session_state['user_info'] = user_info

        email_info = linkedin.get(
            'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))', 
            headers={
                'Authorization': f'Bearer {token["access_token"]}'
            }
        ).json()
        st.session_state['email_info'] = email_info.get('elements', [])[0].get('handle~', {}).get('emailAddress', '')

    except HTTPError as e:
        st.error(f'An HTTP error occurred: {e.response.status_code}')
        st.write(e.response.text)
    except Exception as e:
        st.error(f'An error occurred: {e}')
        st.write(str(e))

# Main App
def main():
    st.title("LinkedIn OpenID Connect Authentication")

    query_params = get_query_params()
    code = query_params.get("code")

    if "oauth_token" not in st.session_state:
        if not code:
            start_oauth()
        else:
            fetch_token_and_user_info(code)
            st.success("Authentication successful!")

    if "user_info" in st.session_state:
        st.write("Your LinkedIn profile information:")
        st.json(st.session_state['user_info'])

        st.write("Your LinkedIn email information:")
        st.write(st.session_state['email_info'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Tried with ChatGPT reading the current documentation, troubleshooting hours and hours. I am a beginner in coding.

Comment: please confirm if the code actually working ?

Comment: The code reliably redirects the user to the linkedin log in and after giving the permission to use the data it redirects the user to the application. But then, the data is not retrieved. Instead, the error in the picture occurs.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.